# Create an Add Instruction in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm-ir

I want to create an add instruction that takes two constant operands at the `LLVM IR` level. I use the `IRBuilder` class, but nothing happens. Here is part of the `runOnFunction()` method of my function pass:

```
LLVMContext &Context = F.getContext();
IRBuilder<> builder(&Instruction);
Value *Lef = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), 4);
Value *Rig = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), 5);
Value *Result = builder.CreateAdd(Lef, Rig);
```

It seems that the problem is with the `ConstantInt::get()` function. Any idea?

Comment: can you list the error message? also the before and after dump of module/function you are trying to modify.

Comment: No error. The problem is the output IR is the same as the input IR. Changing one of the operands to some prebuilt operand such as `op->getOperand(1);` resolves the problem, i.e., the new add will be generated.

Comment: Fortunately, Zhang's advice worked:http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2018-August/125127.html

Comment: Can you add an answer with how you resolved it?